# how to add class 'active' with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I do not know why this does not work. I have no any error in my program. I hope some one could help me resolved this issue.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code in your question. Not only an image.

Comment: where in a link <a> ?

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that says there's an id of firstTag present, have you got the full mark-up and js you can post into the question?

Comment: `$.load` runs asynchronously, so your #firsttTag code runs *before* the html has loaded (given there's no #firstTag in the provided screenshot, it's safe to assume it's loaded in Nav.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a callback at your load function to see if the `Nav.html` is loaded or not, for example:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("Nav.html", function() {
        // Nav was loaded successfully.
        // Add the class
        $("#firstTag").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the difference of this to Rory's answer?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your reply is my answer, and next time I will share the code not the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the `#firstTag` element is within the content you load via the AJAX request. If so, you need to put the `addClass()` call within the callback of the `load()` method so that it's executed *after* the `#firstTag` exists in the DOM. Try this:

```
$('#nav-placeholder').load('Nav.html', function() {
    $('#firstTag').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your replies answered my question.

Comment: You're welcome, although note that it's generally considered most appropriate to give the accepted answer to the person who answered first, if theres two answers which are the same.